# dtype Int64 doesn't return view of underlying data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dtype

I have two dataframes of size `(5, 5)` one of dtype `int64` and another of type [`pd.Int64Dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html).

```
np.random.seed(2021)
data = np.arange(25).reshape((5, 5))
one  = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype='int64')
two  = pd.DataFrame(data.copy(), dtype='Int64') # Notice the capital 'I'
r, c = np.random.randint(0, 5, (2, 5))
```

The problem occurs when I try to change the underlying data.

```
one.to_numpy()[r, c] = 99 # Changes the underlying data
print(one)
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0  99   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8  99
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  99  17  18  19
4  99  99  22  23  24

two.to_numpy()[r, c] = 99 # Doesn't change the underlying data
print(two)
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

I understand that `DataFrame.to_numpy` doesn't necessarily return a view.

> **[`DataFrame.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):**
>
> > **copy**: bool, default False
> >
> > > Whether to ensure that the returned value is not a view on another array. **Note that copy=False does not ensure that to_numpy() is no-copy**. Rather, copy=True ensure that a copy is made, even if not strictly necessary.

How can I change the given positions(`r`, `c`) in DataFrame in a vectorized way? I have a solution using for loop + `.iloc`. For what it's worth, my pandas' version is `1.3.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct that the ExtensionBlocks with dtype `Int64` are not supportive of numpy assignment because they are considered 5 separate blocks rather than a single numeric block. This affects the ability to produce a uniformly modifiable reference to the underlying structures.

You can observe this by accessing the blocks from the manager (note this is just for observation purposes):

```
print('One Blocks')
for blk in one._mgr.blocks:
    print(blk)

print('Two Blocks')
for blk in two._mgr.blocks:
    print(blk)
```

Output:

```
One Blocks
NumericBlock: slice(0, 5, 1), 5 x 5, dtype: int64
Two Blocks
ExtensionBlock: slice(0, 1, 1), 1 x 5, dtype: Int64
ExtensionBlock: slice(1, 2, 1), 1 x 5, dtype: Int64
ExtensionBlock: slice(2, 3, 1), 1 x 5, dtype: Int64
ExtensionBlock: slice(3, 4, 1), 1 x 5, dtype: Int64
ExtensionBlock: slice(4, 5, 1), 1 x 5, dtype: Int64
```

Notice that the DataFrame (`two`) has these as separate underlying structures, meaning that converting to an array calls [_interleave](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/dfe958cc96a5f1b04de464526a81e0f29688510a/pandas/core/internals/managers.py#L1505) which as the comments note "The underlying data was copied within _interleave".

**Note** this is true for *all* DataFrames which contain more than one block.

Meaning something as simple as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': ['a', 'b']})
df.to_numpy()[0, 0] = 5  # No Change
print(df)

   A  B
0  1  a
1  2  b
```

also cannot be modified in this way.

*The blocks for reference

```
# df._mgr.blocks

NumericBlock: slice(0, 1, 1), 1 x 2, dtype: int64
ObjectBlock: slice(1, 2, 1), 1 x 2, dtype: object
```

---

With this in mind, we'd have to use the copy produced by [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) and reconstruct the DataFrame:

```
a = two.to_numpy()  # Store New Array
a[r, c] = 99  # Update The Values
# Reconstruct the DataFrame
two = pd.DataFrame(a, index=two.index, columns=two.columns, dtype='Int64')
```

`astype` can also be used with the known dtypes to ensure columns map to the appropriate dtype (this may be helpful in the instance of multiple dtypes):

```
two = pd.DataFrame(a, index=two.index, columns=two.columns).astype(two.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
print(two)

    0   1   2   3   4
0   0  99   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8  99
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  99  17  18  19
4  99  99  22  23  24


print(two.dtypes)
0    Int64
1    Int64
2    Int64
3    Int64
4    Int64
dtype: object
```

---

Given this singular replacement however, building a 2D mask with numpy is likely the better approach:

```
# Build Boolean Mask (default False)
result = np.zeros(two.shape, dtype='bool')
result[r, c] = True  # Set True Locations
two = two.mask(result, 99)  # DataFrame.mask to replace values
```

Or the inverse mask with `DataFrame.where`:

```
# Build Boolean Mask (default True)
result = np.ones(two.shape, dtype='bool')
result[r, c] = False  # Set False Locations
two = two.where(result, 99)  # DataFrame.where to replace values
```

Both produce:

```
print(two)
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0  99   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8  99
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  99  17  18  19
4  99  99  22  23  24


print(two.dtypes)
0    Int64
1    Int64
2    Int64
3    Int64
4    Int64
dtype: object
```

*Benefit of these approaches is that there is no loss of dtype information.